# BluetoothServerSocket is not returning from the Accept method

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth, block, bluetooth-socket

BluetoothServerSocketInstance.accept() not returning anything
And next step is not executing

Thread blocks at the same place
I have seen many similar questions but unfortunately none of them were helpful to me

I am creating Accept Thread like this

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket

    private String mSocketType;
    boolean isRunning = true;
    private BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread(boolean isAndroid) {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {
            if (isAndroid)
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                        NAME_SECURE, UUID_ANDROID_DEVICE);
            else
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                        NAME_SECURE, UUID_OTHER_DEVICE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED && isRunning) {

            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception

                if (mmServerSocket != null)
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case BluetoothState.STATE_LISTEN:
                    case BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
                                mSocketType);
                        break;
                    case BluetoothState.STATE_NONE:
                    case BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate
                        // new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
            mmServerSocket = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void kill() {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the intended behaviour, it blocks until a connection is succesfully established: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothServerSocket.html#accept%28%29